# How does readline() function really work in Python?

Tags: python, file, readline

Here is my example:

My file:

```
abefgh
2345
6^7&8*
31
1
1
```

My code:

```
handle = open('TestFile','r')
for line in handle:
    print(handle.readline())
```

The output:

```
2345
31
1
```

Why does it only prints alternating lines?

Thank you, everyone. Now I understand that every time I run readline() command. The cursor moves to the end of the line. So the next time it will start to read from the next line.
Please upvote so that I can post questions again. I can't post questions anymore. Thank you in advance!

Comment: The line you want to print is `line`. `handle.readline()` reads *another* line.

Comment: Wait, I thought the readline() function will read from the start of the line/file, right? So if the first line is "abefgh" (in this case this is also considered a file), I think it will read from the start?

Comment: `readline()` reads from a file handle, starting at the current position (whatever that is, after a line, that's at the start of the next line) up to and including the next line ending (or the end of the file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code:

```
handle = open('TestFile','r')
for line in handle:
    print(handle.readline())
```

The loop `for line in handle` already reads one line at time from `handle`. You then read the *next* line using `handle.readline()` and print that. That happens every iteration, so you only get every second line.

The important thing to realise here is that `.readline()` doesn't remember where it is, `handle` does. So, when you open `handle`, it is at the start of the file. Then, when `for` gets the next line, it is at the start the second line. Then `readline()` reads up to and including the end of the next line, so it is at the start of the third line, etc.

You want:

```
handle = open('TestFile','r')
for line in handle:
    print(line)
```

Also, you want to close files and ideally you want to be sure they close without having to worry about closing them yourself, which is what context managers are for. Sounds complicated, but is really quite simple:

```
with open('TestFile', 'r') as handle:
    for line in handle:
        print(line)
```

This works because a file handle like `handle` is also an iterator and provides a `__next__` method. This means that you can loop over it with `for` and it will yield its contents one element at a time. In the case of a text file, that means it will read one line and yield it, every time its `__next__` method is called, either as `next(handle)` or when looped over with `for`.

The `with` block ensures that `handle` is closed, as soon as the `with` block is exited.

Finally, you'll probably end up wondering why your lines are printed with an empty line between them. That's because your file is a text file, where lines are separated by some sort of end of line character (or characters, on Windows).

One way to get rid of those is to strip whitespace off of the end of the line:

```
with open('TestFile', 'r') as handle:
    for line in handle:
        print(line.rstrip())
```

Another way would be to read the whole file, split over line endings and the resulting lines won't have the line ending anymore:

```
with open('TestFile', 'r') as handle:
    for line in handle.read().splitlines():
        print(line)
```

Comment: Ok thanks. I think i slowly get it. About this code:                                                           
handle = open('TestFile','r')
for line in handle:
    print(line). Lol how do I drop line in the comment

Comment: There is no way to nicely present more than a single line of code in a comment, but just ask your follow-up question and I'll try to make sense of it :) - if you need to explain with some code, feel free to edit your question and add the follow-up question to its text.

Comment: Ok thanks. I think i slowly get it. About this code:                                                           
handle = open('TestFile','r') --
for line in handle: -- 
    print(line) -- If i add a line "handle.readline()" in the end, some how it just corrupts the for loop and prints alternating line only (instead print all the lines). How does that possible? I think the for loop will run all over the line no matter what?

Comment: I already answered that more or less in the comments to your question. One step through the for loop causes a single line to be read, so the file handle now points to the start of the next line. `readline()` then reads the next line. Then the next `for` step causes the next to be read, etc.